# Message handler that checks if the current user is blocked in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I was trying to create a message handler that checks if the current user is blocked in ASP.NET MVC 5

But I'm not able to get current user Identity. Am I doing something wrong? or should I try something different? Below is the code for the same.

```cs
using Core.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Serializer;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApi.App_Code
{
    public class BlockedUserMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var manager = request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(ApplicationUserManager)) as ApplicationUserManager;
            var accessTokenFormat = request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>)) as ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>;

            var token = request.Headers.Authorization.ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");
            AuthenticationTicket ticket = accessTokenFormat.Unprotect(token);
           
            if (ticket!=null && ticket.Identity != null)
            {
                var userId = ticket.Identity.GetUserId();
                var user = manager.FindById(userId);
                if (user.IsBlocked)
                {
                    var response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "User is blocked!", request.Content.Headers.ContentType);
                    var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
                    tsc.SetResult(response);
                    return tsc.Task;
                }
            }
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The auth is not set when DelegatingHandler is called. The handlers/filters are called in the order as shown below.
Try deriving from AuthorizationFilterAttribute or ActionFilterAttribute to solve your problem

1. DelegatingHandler, we get a null username

```cs
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

{

    if (request.Headers.Authorization == null)

    {

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

    }



    var context = ((HttpContextBase)request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]);

    var username = context.User.Identity.GetUserName();



    return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

}
```

2. AuthorizationFilterAttribute, we get a valid username

```cs
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)

{

    var context = ((HttpContextBase)actionContext.Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]);

    var username = context.User.Identity.GetUserName();



    base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);

}
```

3. ActionFilterAttribute, we get a valid username

```cs
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)

{

    if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization == null)

    {

        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

        return;

    }



    var context = ((HttpContextBase)actionContext.Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]);

    var username = context.User.Identity.GetUserName();



    base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

}
```